# JS - Fetch response is undefined

Tags: javascript, response, fetch-api

I'm stuck with something weird and I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

To be clear, **my code did work well** for almost all users, but I have in the logs some people having the issue...

These are my API Routes in ExpressJS

```js
router.post("/do-something", async (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send({
        token: '8lAp5hVLUXZFq/laslTWd+GOEcEOeJ58X+Eu2Elg0Q',
        expirationDate: 1695680882748,
        email: 'manu.macron@gmail.com'
    });
})

router.post("/error-log", async (req, res) => {
    const { error } = req.body
    fs.appendFileSync('logs/something-went-wrong.txt', `${ new Date().toLocaleString() } - ${ error }\n`);
    fs.appendFileSync('logs/something-went-wrong.txt', JSON.stringify(UAParser(req.headers['user-agent']), null, 4) + "\n");
    return res.sendStatus(204)
})
```

Now, this is how I implemented my fetch :

```js
fetch("api.com/do-something", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
}).then(async result => {
    const _json = result?.json ? await result.json() : {};
    if(!result?.ok) {
        const error = new Error(result?.statusText || "result = undefined")
        error.code = result?.status || 418
        error.details = Object.keys(_json).length ? _json : null
        throw error;
    }
    // Do something with the token
}).catch(error => {
    fetch("api.com/error-log", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ error: `Someone did fetch but ${error?.details ? JSON.stringify(error.details) : (error instanceof Error ? error.toString() : error)}` })
    }).then(_ => true /*do nothing*/ )
})
```

Just to be sure I repeat that it works fine with almost everybody ... But I have some user experiencing the issue :

```bash
# logs/something-went-wrong.txt
29/08/2023 13:57:10 - Someone did fetch but Error: result = undefined
{
    "ua": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 16_6 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.6 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1",
    "browser": {
        "name": "Mobile Safari",
        "version": "16.6",
        "major": "16"
    },
    "engine": {
        "name": "WebKit",
        "version": "605.1.15"
    },
    "os": {
        "name": "iOS",
        "version": "16.6"
    },
    "device": {
        "vendor": "Apple",
        "model": "iPhone",
        "type": "mobile"
    },
    "cpu": {}
}
```

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong? Or any clue on how to debug it?

Comment: I strongly suggest you adopt `async/await` and stop using `.then()`. Mixing the two is a recipe for mistakes.

Comment: For starters, I would suggest that you be more precise in your error logging. `new Error(result?.statusText || "result = undefined")` - the non-existence or non-truthiness of `result.statusText` does _not necessarily_ mean, that `result` itself was undefined.

Comment: Ok, but how can I debug the Error then ?

Comment: What is the actual value of `result` in these cases? It's not necessarily undefined. Can you log it or use network debug tool to capture it?

Comment: I'll try to log it and came back when I have someone triggered it in the logs ... :(
@Pointy I'll do this but do you really think it will help ?

Comment: It makes the code much simpler; that was the whole point of `async` and `await`.

Comment: What is `result.status` for these broken requests?

Answer (score 2):

If you use fetch, then, I would expect something like this

```js
fetch("api.com/do-something", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
  })
  .then(reponse => response.json())
  .then(result => {
    if (result.token) {
      // Do something with the token
    }
    else {
      const error = new Error(result?.statusText ?? "result = undefined")
      error.code = result?.status || 418
      error.details = Object.keys(result).length || "result: null"
      throw error;
    }

  }).catch(error => {
    fetch("api.com/error-log", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        error: `Someone did fetch but ${error?.details ? JSON.stringify(error.details) : (error instanceof Error ? error.toString() : error)}`
      })
    })
  })
```